# IE9 not printing Google Visualization iframe properly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, google-visualization

I have a barchart that is being displayed using Google Visualization inside an iframe. I am trying to print this with the following code,

```
var iframeEle = $(this).parent().parent().find("iframe");
if(iebrowser) {
    var iedoc = iframeEle[0].contentWindow.document;
    iedoc.execCommand('print', false, null);
} 
else { iframeEle[0].contentWindow.print(); }
```

This is working perfect in IE7/8, FireFox, Chrome....But in IE9 i only get the data back as numbers, and the title back as one long string. Anyone know why IE9 does not like this with a google visualization table?

Comment: well I can't help you with your problem, but your code at least helped me print my hidden iframe in ie9 so thanks.